# How do you verify the Order of the column values in a Web Table in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: list, collections, hashmap, webdriver

WebPage contains web Table. there is few columns. in one column there are values. We need to verify the order of the values in a Column. How? with Selenium WebDriver-Java and TestNG.

Comment: Please provide your code and error stack trace.Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Each column is a WebElement. You need just a List<WebElement> elementsColumns = driver.findElements(By....); than get some attribute of each column (as a String) to List<String> values. Finaly compare collected values with some expected values. List of expected values should be of course in expected order.